# What should I read on json and html parsers to build one myself?

Tags: html, json, parsing, documentation, implementation

I want to create a json and html parser to deepen my knowledge in them (I don't want to reinvent it to be "more efficient", as you could think).
What should I read to succede with it?

P.S: I know about parsing laws, but couldn't find some on json.

P.P.S: C++ implementation is my target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is specified in [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) (using EBNF) and [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-404.htm) (using railroad diagrams). Since they both define the same grammar, which of the two you use is unimportant; go for the one you fibd easier.

JSON parsing is pretty simple. HTML, on the other hand, is a huge project, made more complicated by the absence of a versioned authoritative standard which makes it a bit of a moving target.

HTML parsing as currently defined by the ["living standard"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) is a procedure which probably cannot be encapsulated in a context-free grammar. No real attempt is made to use grammatical descriptions in the standard, although it is possible to extract at least a lexical grammar, if you ignore the sections dealing with the handling of lexical errors.

Certainly, you could write a parser for a well-behaved subset, but that parser might not cope well with many of the "HTML" documents you will want to process. Personally, for learning purposes, I'd suggest trying your hand at [XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/). (Also see [XML Namespaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/)].

Comment: I am really thankful for your detailed response! How do you find this kind of information?